# EnterpriseLibrary PolicyInjectionSettings and Unity 4.0 update compilation error

Tags: c#, unity-container, enterprise-library

I have update to Unity 4.0 and the code below gives me a compilation error with Enterprise Library 6

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

var policyInjectionSettings = (PolicyInjectionSettings)source.GetSection(PolicyInjectionSettings.SectionName);
            policyInjectionSettings.ConfigureContainer(container);
```

The compilation error is: Enterprise Library The type 'IUnityContainer' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=3.0.0.0

Can some one help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Even with on a brand simple console application with only those lines I get that error when I update it from Unity 3.5 to Unity 4.0
I have the problem ONLY when the Unity Package is updated to 4.0 or later, on version 3.5 works fine
I had tried to “patch” the app.config bindingRedirect sections, but no success, still same failure

Answer (score 0):

I had recompiled the PIAB [package](http://piab.codeplex.com) upgrading the Unity packages and the new dll (Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.PolicyInjection.dll) works!!. So indeed the owners of package should update the NugGet Package to Unity 4.0